# How do I send multiple notifications through one channel

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am working on an Android application and I have it so you can send yourself a notification, but I do not know how to send multiple through one channel so it edits the old one. Does anyone know how to do this or if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the id with each post. I can't believe I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, easiest way is using Firebase or Onesignal. Then you have to write small back-end service. After that you can send notifications whatever you want.

Cloud Message: [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging)

OneSignal: [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/)